# UIBarButtonItem sizes differ

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have an app, which uses Storyboards to display two screens. The first one Is a list (referred on screenshot as "Lista"), and the second one is a map ("Térkép"). Each view has a left- and a right navigation button. Pressing the right button pushes the map view to the Navigation Controller. The back button is hidden manually from the map's `viewDidLoad` method.

[image: List view]
[image: Map view]

The question is, that why do the bar button items have different size on each screen? How can I control the size of the buttons?

The images on the buttons are in the same size. Skinning is done in `AppDelegate` through appearance settings:

```
// navbar background
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-titlebar.png"]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// navbar button background
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-main.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-main-active.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
                                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// back button background
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 12.0, 4.0, 4.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back-active.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 12.0, 4.0, 4.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
                                                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: well in my case this formula always has worked for me. May be you are giving bounds to your bar button separately or there should be some orientation issue.

Comment: Questions with images are always appreciated :)

Comment: Try setting the buttons in the viewWillAppear if you are currently using the viewDidLoad

Comment: The buttons have been set up in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get two identical UIBarButtonsItem by creating it in one segue and then copy-pasting the button in another segue (at least this is working in my case but I haven't been able to identify the root cause of the problem so far).

If creating directly a UIBarButtonItem is not working, drop a UIButton in the NavigationItem and it will create automatically a UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton inside (see below image). In this way you can configure an image or other attributes not present in a UIBarButtonItem. Once you are happy with the appearance of your UIButton (embedded in the Bar Button), copy paste it to a different segue and they should keep the same size.

[image: UIBarButtonItem vs UIButton inside UIBarButtonItem]

Comment: And have you tried, instead of dropping and UIBarButtonItem and set the image via the appearance proxy, to drop an UIButton and set the image directly? I know is not so convenient, but I hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: I believe UIButtons dropped into UINavitaionBars become UIBarButtonItems automatically. I have also tried creating the UIBarButtonItems from code, but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, they become UIBarButtonItems, but they are not exactly the same. I just edited the answer to include an image showing a "pure" UIBarButtonItem and another one with a UIButton inside. If like copy-pasting such button is not working for you, then I don't know, sorry. :-(

Comment: Oh, I understand now what you try to tell me :) So let the UIBarButtonItem act as a standard view and put a UIButton inside this. This is a nice workaround, it seems working. I keep using this until I found a real solution, thanks!

Comment: Ok, great. Let me know if you find the root cause, but I even think is a problem of the current XCode version because, sometimes, I'm not able to view the image of the button in the storyboard (showing with a question mark and different size but showing properly in the simulator and in the device). Opening and closing XCode sometimes solves the problem sometimes not. Anyway, quite likely we will have next week the iOS 7 beta SDK, so let's see what's happening then with the buttons.

Comment: I didn't find the root of the problem, but this workaround works fine. Thanks!